# Debugging options for React Native using Expo 50 using Redux

Tags: reactjs, debugging, expo, native

Just looking for opinions if possible, I’ve been using React Native with Redux in Expo. Expo 50 has been released which has deprecated React Native Debugger.

React Native Debugger was great because it had Redux Devtools which I find essential for using redux.

I’ve tried to set up a few other debuggers - Flipper comes standard now with new versions bare React Native but with Expo I’ve found it hard to setup anything other than the standard chrome JS debugger but that doesn’t seem to have redux devtools. Even when I tried to use bare react native with flipper I couldn’t get the redux debugger plugin to work and now there seems to be a ui bug on flipper preventing installing other plugins.

In short I’m trying to figure out my next steps, should I completely abandon Redux now and try start using a new state management tool. I’ve heard for Mobx but not sure if I’ll have the same issues?

Or should I stick with redux and try use it without redux dev tools?